# Is it possible to make Clustered double column/stacked column chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to plot a chart with 2 columns on same chart and i want it to be grouped by third category "Code"
Currently my chart looks like this , Light blue colour represents "FirstSize" and dark blue represents "SecondSize" , x-axis has "Account Name".

[image]

However , I want the above graph to group the stacked columns based on the third category "Code" , The below example shows the third category values "M" , FR", "BR" , "D" etc... and then may be use a different color along with these two represent two type of sizes ( stacked )

[image]

So , I want to be able to do something like adding a Column Series "Code" in the below settings to make it work.

[image]

Is it possible via any visual ?

Answer (score 0):

You need some transformation in your data to achieve your required output. For say, If I am correct you have now data in this below format-

```
code    firstsize    secondsize
code1   10           20
code2   25           30
```

You have to transform your above data and as below which is basically an un pivot of data-

```
code    size        value
code1   firstsize   10
code1   secondsize  20
code2   firstsize   25
code2   secondsize  30
```

Now you can configure your Stacked Column chart as below to get your desired output.

```
Code as Axis
Size as Legend
Value as Values
```